# Loading apps while iPhone starts up (boots) or after a shutdown

Tags: iphone, ios, loading, startup, boot

For non-jailbreak iPhones, is there a way to let your program load when the phone starts? And is there a way to schedule application startup at specific times?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, thats not possible. The only thing that might help you to launch an application at a specific time is a `UILocalNotification` but it only allows fixed times and not relative ones like "two seconds after XY" and it isn't guaranteed to really start the app because it depends on user input.

Comment: Is there a sample code for starting apps based on local notifications? (while the app is not in the background?)

Comment: @ASH Its not that hard to setup a local notification, just check the `UILocalNotification` class reference. But keep in mind, this won't automatically start your app but let the user decide if s/he wants to start your app!